# All Metabase operations returning "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, metabase, aws-aurora-serverless

We're moving our Metabase v0.24.1 deployment from AWS RDS MySQL 5.7 to AWS Aurora MySQL Serverless (5.6 compatible). When we launch Metabase every query the the application tries to run returns will some form of this error:

```
Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

Full Error:

```
03-17 16:07:57 [1mERROR metabase.middleware[0m :: [31mPOST /api/database 500 (68 ms) (0 DB calls)[0m
{:message "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value",
 :stacktrace
 ["api.database$fn__29894$fn__29897.invoke(database.clj:233)"
  "api.common.internal$do_with_caught_api_exceptions.invokeStatic(internal.clj:229)"
  "api.common.internal$do_with_caught_api_exceptions.invoke(internal.clj:224)"
  "api.database$fn__29894.invokeStatic(database.clj:215)"
  "api.database$fn__29894.invoke(database.clj:215)"
  "middleware$enforce_authentication$fn__38784.invoke(middleware.clj:120)"
  "api.routes$fn__38908.invokeStatic(routes.clj:58)"
  "api.routes$fn__38908.invoke(routes.clj:58)"
  "routes$fn__39540$fn__39541.doInvoke(routes.clj:64)"
  "routes$fn__39540.invokeStatic(routes.clj:60)"
  "routes$fn__39540.invoke(routes.clj:60)"
  "middleware$log_api_call$fn__38883$fn__38885.invoke(middleware.clj:329)"
  "middleware$log_api_call$fn__38883.invoke(middleware.clj:328)"
  "middleware$add_security_headers$fn__38833.invoke(middleware.clj:243)"
  "middleware$bind_current_user$fn__38788.invoke(middleware.clj:140)"
  "middleware$maybe_set_site_url$fn__38837.invoke(middleware.clj:266)"],
 :sql-exception-chain ["SQLException:" "Message: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value" "SQLState: HY000" "Error Code: 1364"]}
```

Attempts to add a new database also return the same error through the Metabase UI.

We have validated that the RDS db parameters are identical between the database we are migrating to and from excluding the engine default configurations that may change between Aurora Serverless and MySQL 5.7 defaults.

Another notable change is that we're moving from normal ECS tasks running on EC2 instances that we own over to Fargate tasks, but the task definitions are identical between the two.

Edit: I've found another configuration inconsistency between Aurora Serverless and MySQL 5.7 in the `sql_mode` parameter. In 5.7, it is set to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` by default and in serverless it is set to `0`.

After updating `sql_mode` on my serverless deployment to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` I've found that the actual configuration remains inconsistent in the database itself. `SELECT @@sql_mode;` returns `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` on the 5.7 deployment and it returns `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` on the serverless deployment even though the parameter group is not set to this value.

Edit 2: I failed to mention the method that we are using to transfer the data to the new database and that is AWS DMS version 3.3.1. It appears that DMS does not replicate the `auto_increment` table attribute which needs to be present on the `id` columns in the Metabase database. This could likely be the root issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was that the `id` columns in the Metabase DB did not have the `auto_increment` attribute and were being treated as if they did not have values even though they did.

This was because, AWS DMS, which we used to transfer the data, does not replicate all details of the schema:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138946/aws-dms-creates-tables-with-no-auto-increment

The fix to this issue was to perform a schema migration first using a standard `mysqldump --no-data` and then we populated the data with DMS.

Comment: Hey @jjno91, I'm curious about your experience using Aurora Serverless for the Metabase db - what does the monthly bill look like? In theory I imagine there would be cost savings but I have no idea how frequently Metabase accesses its db while idle.